# Capacity planning for EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

We are planning to use EMR cluster to process 80 GB of Parquet data. And we wanted to plan the total core and task nodes needed for this. I came across [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/amazon-emr-hardware/capacity.html) documentation from AWS for planning capacity.

For capacity planning of task nodes, the documentation assumes this

*Suppose that you have 28 processes of 20 GiB each.*

My question here is what is this 28 processess of 20 GB? Are they executors?

Answer (score 0):

You can run various application on AWS EMR, so those are abstract processes: for example, in the case of a Spark application, those are executors, and in the case of a Hadoop MapReduce job, those are mappers and reducers. Have a look at page [Overview of Amazon EMR architecture](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-overview-arch.html) for more information.